# Can TXL be used for code clone detection

Tags: c++, frameworks, clone, detection

Can we use [TXL](http://www.txl.ca/index.html) language for code clone detection (especially for analyzing C/C++ codes) considering only Text-based and Token-based Approaches?

If yes, then can we further integrate it with a framework to make a final dashboard which can be used to detect the clones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can. Code clone detector such as : [NiCad clone Detector](http://www.txl.ca/nicaddownload.html) has been developed on the TXL language. It involves three main stages: *parsing, normalization, and comparison*, which almost covers both the text-based and token-based approaches.

You may click on this [link](http://www.cs.queensu.ca/~cordy/Papers/CR-NiCad-Tool-ICPC11.pdf) to get the detailed documentation of the NiCad.